# If a value is selected in dropdown, show a button else hide it

Tags: jquery

I am new to stack exchange so beg pardon if anything wrong

I am trying to show a button only if the user selects something from the provided dropdown. if he has not considered it then keep it hidden.

I am new to jquery, by the way

my html code is

```
<div id="mos">
<div id="mosblock" class="moseffect stitched">
    <aside>
        <div class="textwidget widget-text">
            <div id='chainselect_wrap' class='branch cs_count_1'>
                <select name="branch" id='chainlist_1' >
                    <option>Select Branch</option>
                    <option value='33'>Aeronautical Engineering (AE) (12)</option>
                    <option value='28'>Automobile engineering (14)</option>
                    <option value='35'>Bio-Technology (BT) (12)</option>
                    <option value='34'>BioMedical Engineering (BE) (12)</option>
                    <option value='36'>Chemical Engineering (CE) (12)</option>
                    <option value='32'>Civil Engineering (17)</option>
                    <option value='51'>common to all (8)</option>
                    <option value="61">Computer Engineering(CE) (18)</option>
                </select>
       <input type='hidden'id='chainselects_taxurl'value='' />        
       <input type='hidden' id='chainselects_siteurl' value='something.com' />
       <input name="findbranch" type='button' id="brancher" value='Find' />
        <span id='chainselects_loading'></span>
            </div>
        </div>
     </aside>
</div>
```

my **css** is

`#brancher{ display:none;}`

and finally since i am new to **jquery** maybe its wrong but it is

```
 if ($("#chainlist_1 option").val() !== '' ) {
     $("#brancher").show();
 }
```

here is a jsfiddle of what i want to do
http://jsfiddle.net/x78b7941/
 I am trying it from hours but dont know whats happening wrong

one more thing, can I skip javascript and directly learn jquery or is it required. Any thoughts ??

plz help, every response is valuable to me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Include jquery in your fiddle.

Comment: I appreciate all for your valuable answers, thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to use `.change()` along with `.toggle()` function to achieve what you want,

```
$("#chainlist_1").change(function () {
    $("#brancher").toggle(!isNaN(+$(this).val()));
});
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/x78b7941/9/)

Comment: thanks man, its working in the demo let me see if it works on my site

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for something like this:

```
$("#chainlist_1").on("change", function() {
      $("#brancher").show();
});
```

In jquery you attach events to the DOM elements, so what we're doing here is waiting to the select value to change and then show the button.

here's the fiddle updated [UPDATED](http://jsfiddle.net/x78b7941/8/)

Comment: thanks man, but i also want it to go away if user selects nothing again, thanks by the way

Answer (score 0):

The value of first option of select should be blank:

```
//jquery
$(function(){
    $("#chainlist_1").on("change",function(){
        if ($(this).val() != '' ) {
            $("#brancher").show();
        } else {
            $("#brancher").hide();
        }
    });
});

    //php
    <div id="mos">
    <div id="mosblock" class="moseffect stitched">
        <aside>
            <div class="textwidget widget-text">
                <div id='chainselect_wrap' class='branch cs_count_1'>
                    <select name="branch" id='chainlist_1' >
                        <option value=''>Select Branch</option> <!-- value is blank -->
                        <option value='33'>Aeronautical Engineering (AE) (12)</option>
                        <option value='28'>Automobile engineering (14)</option>
                        <option value='35'>Bio-Technology (BT) (12)</option>
                        <option value='34'>BioMedical Engineering (BE) (12)</option>
                        <option value='36'>Chemical Engineering (CE) (12)</option>
                        <option value='32'>Civil Engineering (17)</option>
                        <option value='51'>common to all (8)</option>
                        <option value="61">Computer Engineering(CE) (18)</option>
                    </select>
           <input type='hidden'id='chainselects_taxurl'value='' />        
           <input type='hidden' id='chainselects_siteurl' value='something.com' />
           <input name="findbranch" type='button' id="brancher" value='Find' />
            <span id='chainselects_loading'></span>
                </div>
            </div>
         </aside>
    </div>
```